# C# WPF and SQL Server Reporting

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, rdlc

I have a database that I'm trying to print reports from.  My data input is done through a C# WPF application and so I've added a "Print" button on my main view (MVVM) that creates a new window and viewmodel.  The window is has a windowsFormsHost and it creates a ReportViewer control:

```
public partial class Report : Window
{
    private bool _isReportViewerLoaded;
    public Report(FlatObservationViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _reportViewer.Load += ReportViewer_Load;
    }

    private void ReportViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_isReportViewerLoaded)
        {
            Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource reportDataSource1 = new
            Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource();

            this._reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "MOATools.FieldObervationReport.rdlc";

            _reportViewer.RefreshReport();
            _isReportViewerLoaded = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Using the Report Designer I've created the report (FieldObervationReport.rdlc) which has a misspelling that I'll fix when I figure all of this out, but for now I'm running with it.  The report designer lets me add datasets/ datasources from the ReportData Pane, and I am trying to use a viewmodel class that I specifically set up for the report:

```
public class FlatObservationViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public FlatObservationViewModel(Projectinformation p, Reportinformation r, PMToolsDCDataContext dc)
    {
        Project = p;
        Report = r;
        Obs = new ObservableObservations(dc, r.Reportdate, p.ID);
    }

    public Projectinformation Project { get; set; }
    public Reportinformation Report { get; set; }
    public ObservableObservations Obs { get; set; }
    public int DivNum { get; set; }
    public int ObsNum { get; set; }
    public string DivName { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public string OpenDate { get; set; }
    public string CloseDate { get; set; }
}
```

When I added the DataSet to the report I named it ReportVMDS and it shows all of the fields from the ViewModel class that I want.  But I can't figure out how to set up the ReportViewer to properly bind to the dataset and datasource that I set up in the Visual Studio GUI.  Because I have a WPF application I don't get the windows forms controls to drag onto the WindowsFormsHost and all of the tutorials I have found are based on setting up the ReportViewer in the GUI.  The ReportViewer_Load handler I think is where I need to add my dataset and initialize it, but the dataset that the reportdesigner sets up (ReportVMDS) is not a valid class, so if I try this:

```
ReportVMDS dataset = new ReportVMDS();
```

I get the error: "The type or namespace not found" and the red squiggly underline in the code.  When I run the program and press the print button, my window opens and tells me that a datasource instance has not been supplied.

So I think I need some pointers on how to wire up my reporting with my viewmodels, using DI, and then getting the GUI reporting design also to work with the view models with the DataSource and DataSet.

Any help is appreciated!  I am using LinqToSQL to get to populate my viewmodels if that makes any difference.

Comment: http://selvin.pl/WPFPrintingMVVM.zip  MainWindow is not in MVVM but preview is ... and it is reusable with different rdlc and different data ... data should be simple POCO and should be added as object source ... RealInvoiceModel/RealInvoiceElement could be your master/detail ViewModel

Comment: ...Save should call some service method instead implementing directly saving ... same story with message box ...  ExportCommand should be some ready to use async ICommand implementation(im using Catel so it is TaskCommand)

Comment: @Selvin Thanks again . . . I will dig into what you have, as it will serve as a great template.  In the meantime I have decided to add a dataset and created stored procedures to take care of flattening the data.